# Cannot retrieve tab data after envelope is reassigned

Tags: php, docusignapi

When I create an envelope and set tabs, if the envelope gets reassigned to another person, all of the tab data is null when retrieved with the API.

I create an envelope from a PDF with text anchors. I set the tabs and send it. If the original recipient completes the envelope, I can retrieve the tab data with the API using ListTabs()

If the original recipient reassigns the envelope to another person, when I use ListTabs(), all of the tab values are null.

```
$textTabs = array();
$name = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text;
$name->setAnchorString('{{name}}');
$name->setDocumentId(1);
$name->setName('Name');
$name->setTabLabel('name');
$name->setWidth(200);
$textTabs[] = $name;
$tabs = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs;
$tabs->setTextTabs($textTabs);

$signer = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer;
$signer->setRecipientId(1);
$signer->setRoutingOrder(1);
$signer->setEmail($recipientEmail);
$signer->setName($recipientName);
$signer->setRoleName('agent');
$signer->setTabs($tabs);
```

If the envelope has been reassigned, the tabs are empty:

```
$envelope = $envelopeApi->getEnvelope($accountId,$envelopeId);
$tabs = $envelopeApi->listTabs($accountId, $envelopeId, 1);
var_dump($tabs);
```

Result:

```
object(DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs)#6 (1) {
["container":protected]=>
array(25) {
["approve_tabs"]=>
NULL
["checkbox_tabs"]=>
NULL
... etc
```

All fields are null. If the envelope has not been reassigned, I can access all of the tabs I originally set when I created the envelope.

UPDATE:
With help from Drew, I got what I needed. I simply retrieved the recipient ID from the document and passed it to the listTabs call like so:

```
$rs = $envelopeApi->listRecipients($accountId,$envelopeId);
$recipientId = '';
foreach($rs["signers"] as $s) {
    $recipientId = $s["recipient_id_guid"];
}
$tabs = $envelopeApi->listTabs($accountId, $envelopeId, $recipientId);
```

Works for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signer Reassignment likely results in the user who takes action having a different recipient ID. If you pull the recipient info for that new ID, you should find your tag data.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I don't know much about the DocuSign universe. I will give that a try and update here with my results. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Also try the [EnvelopeFormData::get](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeFormData/get) API call to obtain the current tab values.

Comment: This would have worked but I would have had to make some code changes. Retrieving the recipient ID and passing it to the call allowed me to keep all the rest of my code the same, so that was easiest for me.